Unable to identify OPC-UA variables
I'm working on a project aimed at reading sensor data from a CNC grinding machine via a OPC-UA interface. It has an integrated OPC server which is already configured. The software running on the machine is SIEMENS Sinumeric. I connected to the server using the UA Expert client. Now I have about 3000 variables infront with names that are either hard to interpret or completely unidentifiable.
My question is if anyone has experience with this sort of issue and if you have a suggestion on how to tackle it.
I already contacted the technical support of the machines manufacturer but they weren't able to help, since they don't have any experiency with OPC-UA. I assume the OPC-UA interface and server were implemented to make the machine future-proof but the setup and documentation (which I don't have) weren't thought through.

What type of Sinumerik system does your machine have?  e.g. Sinumerik 840D sl, ONE, 828D.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

It is likely that the OPC UA part conforms with OPC UA companion standard "OPC 40502-1: CNC Systems", which you can find here: https://reference.opcfoundation.org/CNC/v100/docs/ .
